# React-native component, adding child as component.button

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to create a component with the name of 'MyComponent' and also want to add the child elements as < myComponent.Button />.

```
<MyComponent selected={this.state.activeTab} onSelected={this.onTabSelect}>
   <MyComponent.Button name='child1' text='text1' />
   <MyComponent.Button name='child2' text='text2'/>
   <MyComponent.Button name='child3' text='text3'/>
</myComponent>
```

How to structure component in react-native, so that i can call the component as mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am taking an example from `PickerIOS` and `PickerIOS.Item`.

Create your `MyComponent` component which will render `this.props.children` like so:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

Then you can create your `Button` like so

```
MyComponent.Button = class extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Button title="Hello" onPress={() => {}} />;
  }
};
```

And then you can declare your components like so

```
<MyComponent>
  <MyComponent.Button />
</MyComponent>
```

I have taken off some of your props for the purposes of this demonstration.

Comment: Getting error when i define button child as you mentioned. Do we need to give some class name for button component and then assign it to   MyComponent.Button?                                                              MyComponent.Button = class extends Component {

Comment: Which error are you getting? Are you using ES6 + JSX?

Comment: here => MyComponent.Button = class extends Component.. I think we need to give class name for this?  MyComponent.Button = class mychildElement extends Component

Comment: Are you declaring `MyComponent.Button` inside of a separate file to `MainComponent`? You don't need to define a name because you're registering Button as a static identifier on `MyComponent`

Comment: I have created class MyComponent in one file. In the Same file, I am doing   export const  MyComponent = MyComponentxxx;
MyComponent.Button = class extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Button title='Hello' onPress={() => {}} />;
  }
};